# Get min value of nested array in Spark Dataset

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I have a JSON server log file that I want to parse using Spark 2.2.0 and Java API, which I convert to a Dataset using

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(args[0]);
```

Then, it generates the following schema:

```
df.printschema();

root
|-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
|-- results: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- entities: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- entity_id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- score: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- is_available: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |-- number_of_results: long (nullable = true)
```

I want to get the entity with the lowest score and that is available, so I would get a Dataset similar to:

```
 root
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- results: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entity: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- entity_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- is_available: boolean (nullable = true)
```

How can I do this transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a user defined function on your array column :

```
// Define the UDF that takes the min of array
UDF1<Seq<Row>, Row> getElement = seq -> {
    Row bestRow = null;
    long bestRowScore = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Row r : JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(seq)){
        if (r.getBoolean(1) && r.getLong(2)<bestRowScore){
            bestRow = r;
            bestRowScore = r.getLong(2);
        }
    }
    return bestRow;
};

// Define the return type of UDF
ArrayType arrayType = (ArrayType) df.select(df.col("results.entities")).schema().fields()[0].dataType();
DataType elementType = arrayType.elementType();

// Register UDF
sparkSession.udf().register("getElement", getElement, elementType);

// Apply UDF on dataset
Dataset<Row> transformedDF = df.select(df.col("timestamp"),functions.callUDF("getElement", df.col("results.entities")));
transformedDF.printSchema();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function (row number for example) to achieve that:

```
df.registerTempTable("df");
val minPerEntityDF = spark.sql("SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by entity.entity_id order by score asc) as rn 
 FROM df")
.filter("rn = 1")
```